# problemas con selenium y excel

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver

espero su apoyo tengo un problema con una automatización con excel y selenium he venido trabajando normal hasta hace un tiempo y se presento al querer trabajar con el argumento **.AddArgument "--headless"** he actualizado el selenium y usando la versión actualizada del **chromedriver** pero que da un error al hacer más de 2 consultas adjunto una imagen del error a ver si alguien puede apoyarme.

With Chrome
.AddArgument "--headless"
.Get "sanciones.gob.pe/Sanciones/solicitudacceso;jsessionid=abc" .FindElementById("nrodocumento").SendKeys FormClientBV.txtDNI .FindElementById("eventlink").Click
End With

[image: imagen]

Comment: Te agradecería que nos mostraras el código que estas programando y nos mostraras el error que te muestra por pantalla si no así no seré capaz de ayudarte. Por cierto no veo la imagen del error que has adjuntado.

Comment: gracias ese es el código que utilizo para mi consulta, al hacer el llamado me funciona bien la primera consulta pero al realizar una segunda es en donde me sale error

With Chrome
.AddArgument "--headless"
.Get "https://www.sanciones.gob.pe/Sanciones/solicitudacceso;jsessionid=abc"
.FindElementById("nrodocumento").SendKeys FormClientBV.txtDNI
.FindElementById("eventlink").Click
End With

Comment: @robertgaray el código va en la pregunta y no en la zona de comentarios

Comment: muchas gracias ya corregí la pregunta y puse el código como sede soy nuevo en el foro espero alguien pueda ayudarme